# SQLite locking file even though connection is closed

Tags: c#, sqlite

Shouldn`t the following statement be **autocommited**? I get an **IOException** trying to delete the file after executing the query.

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\test.db;Version=3;"))
{
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (id INTEGER)", connection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

//throwing an IOException
File.Delete(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\test.db");
```

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: The exception is: "The process cannot access the file 'data\test.db' because it is being used by another process."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but I had to:

```
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
```

Prior to calling File.Delete().

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the SQLiteCommand also Dispose(able)? The connection might not close because you haven't closed the command yet. I'd use a using for that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to dispose of every **SQLiteConnection**, **SQLiteCommand** and **SQLiteDataReader** once you are done using it. Simply create the **SQLiteCommand** within a "using" block and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is – I just read the [source code](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/source/browse/) to the C# client and C# implementation of sqlite, and there's nothing obvious – so maybe you just need to wait a few seconds for the OS to finish writing things back to disk before it is all ready to be deleted?

Of course, if it isn't that much data then you should just use an in-memory database. Why bother the filesystem with the data if you don't have to? You need this connection string:

```
Data Source=file::memory:;Version=3;
```

Comment: even after waiting several seconds or minutes the file isn`t unlocked.
the listing was only a simplification of the actual code. but thank you for that hint.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to close the connection after the query execution?

`connection.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using `PRAGMA locking_mode = EXCLUSIVE;`, but set it back to `PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL;` before closing the connection. This caused the connection's lock to not get released.